# GoogleMap shows different location each day

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm tryin to sort out why google maps behave diffrently after than a day before.

I recently put my customer's website online. There was an error with geolocation and I fixed it. Did not fix it on test site tho.

Today, on both sides (fixed one and test one) my geolocation started to show searched location in center of Africa. I'm really clueless what's going on. It works, next day it doesn't.

Not saying it also stopped showing YellowPin, why?

```
        var map;
        var mapOptions;
        var markerOwn = null;
        function searchLocations()
        {

            var address = document.getElementById('addressInput').value;
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                    if(markerOwn === null){
                        markerOwn = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 20),
                            customInfo: "<br><center><b>Jesteś Tutaj!</b></center>",
                            flat: false,

                            icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/ylw-pushpin.png', // user :)

                            title: "Twoja lokacja",

                        });
                        addInfoWindow(markerOwn);
                    } 
                    markerOwn.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.ob, results[0].geometry.location.pb ) );
                    google.maps.event.trigger(markerOwn,'click');
                    map.panTo(results[0].geometry.location);
                }
            });

        }
```

You can see code in action here: http://spafoodbistro.pl/index.php?page=gdzie-jestesmy

Edit:
What I changed earlier was in

```
 markerOwn.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.ob, results[0].geometry.location.pb ) );
```

earlier I used different value to fetch coordinates, now I use:

```
 results[0].geometry.location.ob to get it.
```

Why it changes? maybe that's whats wrong since it changed last time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you mix up latitude and longitude, and `results[0].geometry.location` is already a `LatLng` object, so you can simply use

```
markerOwn.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
```

Which works for me.

Comment: Just solved it a while ago, was about to answer this question. After reading some docs I found it was already a LatLng object. Thank you for your answer tho!